# Where can I find 下江人's article《释四川话 (二)》from《旅行杂志》1945/7/18?

Tags: reference-materials

**四川方言词源** has the following information under the entry for *搊贺*:

> 又，下江人《释四川话(二)》： “救济□人，或扶助他人成 功，称为‘抽合’。”(《旅行杂志》1945/7/18)此记音。

The article is then referenced again under the entry for *打启发*:

> 又，下江人 《释四川话 (二)》： “打抽丰称 ‘打起发’。” (《旅行杂志》1945/7/18)

CADAL (China Academic Digital Associative Library) has an issue here: [旅行杂志](http://www.cadal.zju.edu.cn/book/view/07080411)

> [image: 旅行杂志]

Which says:

> 民国三十四年

which apparently works out to:

》[image: 民国三十四年]

1945

then the next part says:

> 第十九卷第七期

Vol. 19/NO. 7

but the table of contents also says:

[image: yup]

I'm not sure what **四川方言词源**'s reference of《旅行杂志》1945/7/18 exactly means.
1945 is the year; if 7 is the month that corroborates with the issue on CADAL which says 七月 on the cover.

p. 2 says:

> [image: yes]

7/31

Does that mean 《旅行杂志》1945/7/18 would be the earlier issue: Vol. 19/No. 6?

but then that article says:

[image: a]

> Vol. 19/No. 6
>
> 六月三十日

1945 Vol. 19/No. 7 does have an article titled:《释四川话》| the reference in **四川方言词源** says《释四川话 (二)》though - with a #2. I'm struggling to figure this out though.

Any ideas?

---

another example of a reference from the same book looks like this:

> 白虹《四川方言 (川行杂记之 六)》： “锅块，烧饼也。” (《自修》 1941/162/24)

'41 is most likely the year

and another:

> (中华书局， 1938/182)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation system works like:

- year/issue/page

Making: 1945/7/18, issue number seven from 1945 page 18.

---

There are three parts in the one magazine.

Part one can be found on page 8:

[image]

Part two is on page 18:

[image]

Part three is on page 35:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1945/7/18 is the common format of year/month/day.

But given that the 6th issue is published on 6/30, the 7th issue is more likely to be published on 7/31.

Can you check it again and post the picture with the entry 搊贺?

Comment: The info is from CNKI actually - but I have at least three entries so far that all read "下江人《释四川话 (二)《旅行杂志》 1945/7/18" || here's another: 打来吃起 ----- 把别人的东西据为己有。下江人《释四川话 (二)》： “没 (?) 财中饱叫 ‘打来吃起’。” (《旅行杂志》 1945/7/18)

Comment: I edited my Q || another example of a reference from the same book looks like this: `白虹《四川方言 (川行杂记之 六)》： “锅块，烧饼也。” (《自修》 1941/162/24)` || '41 is most likely the year but what's 162/24? VOL/NO?

Comment: It's very strange to see 162/24 because the custom is Year/Month/Day. If possible you should get physical access to the journal because I feel there may be typos when they scan the books and put them in computers.

Comment: Yeah I could understand if it's wrong once but three plus times shouldn't really be wrong - especially since the reference is exactly the same each time. Perhaps it's year/page or something like that

Comment: Another: 
摸包儿 mo55baor55     mo55paor55

扒窃。民国二十九年《开阳县志稿》第九章《社会·社团》： “或白昼摸包剪绺，施放闷烟，取人钱财。”亦说“摸包包”。下江 人《释四川话 (二)》： “扒手剪绺称做 ‘摸包包’。”扒手谓 “摸 狗”。又： “小偷为 ‘贼(读若最)娃子’ ‘摸狗’。” (《旅行杂志》 1945/7/18)今亦说“摸哥”。

Comment: Again I think 1945/7/18 is most likely to be YYYY/M/DD format. It's second likely to be Year/Volume/Issue format. Chinese custom is start from a broader category to a narrow category so it's Volume/Issue rather than Issue/Volume. But it's very rare to see a publication which has 18 issues in a year. So I still think this refer to 1945, July 18.

Comment: found a different one: 下江人《释 四川话(三)》： “‘讪谭子’ 和 ‘扯坝子’ 是说笑与说谎。”(《旅行 杂志》1945/7/35)

Comment: I've no idea what does 35 mean. Maybe you could ask the libertarian from where you got the book.

Answer (score -1):

自修 is a reference to "original research" or self-study.  Perhaps the author's own notes are being referenced?